# Gtools mixedsort not working as expected on numeric string

Tags: r

I have a string

```r
str1 <- "T-759..780, -D-27..758_E, -D-781..1338_C"
```

And I tried to use `gtools::mixedsort` to order these comma separated strings.

```r
sapply(strsplit(str1 , ','), function(x) toString(gtools::mixedsort(x)))
```

I get

```
" -D-781..1338_C,  -D-27..758_E, T-759..780"
```

I am expecting

```
"-D-27..758_E, T-759..780 -D-781..1338_C"
```

Not sure what I need to do to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a misconception on how `mixedsort()` works. It doesn't sort by the numbers in the string, it splits a string in separate string and number parts and sorts all of them in order. I hope these small example illustrate how `mixedsort()` works. It starts by sorting the elements of the vector `c("B_1", "A_2", "A_10")` by their first string-part `c("B", "A", "A")`, so `A` is always before `B` and then for the two `A`-elements it sorts them by their numbers `10` and `2`:

```r
# example showing how mixedsort works
example <- c("B_1", "A_2", "A_10")
gtools::mixedsort(example)
#> [1] "A_2" "A_10" "B_1"

sort(example) # in comparison to normal sort, which doesn't recognize parts of the string as numbers
#> [1] "A_10" "A_2" "B_1"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

But according to your example, you want to sort a vector by the first number, which appears in each element, and ignore a possible `-` infront of the number. In that case, you can just use a regular expression to extract the first number in a string with `gsub(".*?([0-9]+).*", "\\1", x)` and use that to sort the vector. I wrote a small function for it:

```r
# function to sort by first number, ignoring minus before the number
sort.first.number <- function(x) {
  v <- gsub(".*?([0-9]+).*", "\\1", x)
  x[order(v)]
}

str1 <- "T-759..780, -D-27..758_E, -D-781..1338_C"
sapply(strsplit(str1 , ','), function(x) toString(sort.first.number(x)))
#> [1] " -D-27..758_E, T-759..780,  -D-781..1338_C"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>